# How do I plot a surface graph in Excel where the first column is X, 2nd is Y, and 3rd is height of the surface?

Tags: excel-charts

Suppose I have 3 columns of number in Excel.   The first column might be height.   The second column might be weight. The third column might be lifespan.   I want to plot the third column as a surface in an X, Y graph, where the first column is the x-axis coordinate, the second column is the y-axis coordinate, and the third column is the height of the surface.   Which graph type will work best?